# Empty game folder stays after uninstallation - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to make uninstaller delete it?

P.S. I'm afraid that using **Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}"** inside **[UninstallDelete]** section with delete the entire GAMES folder.

Help! ^^

Comment: If the installer created the folder and there are no remaining files in the folder, the uninstaller will delete it by default. So either the folder existed before the installation already, or you have something wrong in the script. Or do you want the installer remove the empty folder, even if the installer did not create it? Show us your script.

Comment: Are you sure that the target folder is not locked by any other program? For example I found that this problem may occur if you start the uninstaller directly via double click from Windows Explorer, EVEN if you navigated outside the folder before uninstaller finished. So did you check that it is really a problem of the uninstaller? Try install and uninstall without opening the folder in explorer in between and see if it works. If so, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UninstallDelete] 
Type: dirifempty; Name: {app};
```

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment, deleting `{app}` folder in `UninstallDelete` with `dirifempty` flag makes sense only if you need to delete the folder, even if it existed **before the first installation**, what is unlikely. Otherwise the directive is redundant, as the uninstaller removes the `{app}` folder on its own.

Comment: If there exists the directory \dirname and your app is being installed into this directory (**you will be prompted that folder already exists**), on uninstall phase this directory is not removed. If you want it to be removed, apply the answer of this comment. (Just validating what @MartinPrikryl mentioned)